# Have a question about Chef variables, can't seem to get the variables to work

Tags: ruby, linux, chef-infra

I'm trying to use server roles to add data into a template. I tried a couple of methods and can't seem to get it to work.

Here is the role code block.

```
ruby_block 'get_main_role_attr' do
block do
  require 'mixlib/shellout'
  rolecmd = Mixlib::ShellOut.new("cat /var/chef/role | cut -d',' -f 1 | cut -c2-")
  rolecmd.run_command
  rolecmd.error!
  node.normal['mainrole'] = rolecmd.stdout
 end
end

template "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" do
  source "ssh/sshd_config.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0600"
  action :create
  variables(
    :allowed_users_team1 => "AllowUsers user1 user2 user3",
    ) if node['mainrole'] == "role1"
  notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
  variables(
    :allowed_users_team2 => "AllowUsers user4 user5 user6",
    ) if node['mainrole'] == "role2" || node['mainrole'] ==  "role3" || node['mainrole'] == "role4"
  notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
end
```

Method 1

```
variables(
    :allowed_users => "AllowUsers user1 user2",
    ) if node['mainrole'] == "role1" || node['mainrole'] ==  "role2" ||    node['mainrole'] == "role3"
notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
```

Method 2

```
variables(
   :allowed_users => "AllowUsers user1 user2",
   ) if node['mainrole'] == "role1" || "role2" || "role3"
notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
```

Method 3

```
variables(
   :allowed_users_bidder => "AllowUsers user1 user2",
) if node['roles'].any? {|r| %w{role1 role2 role3}.include?(r)}
notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
```

Let me knwo what I'm doign wrong please.. Thank you for the help

Thx

Comment: "can't seem to get it to work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Sorry, I have multiple variable blocks for a template. I'm trying to apply data to the file on the server, according to the chef role. Role1 should have a certain set of users, role2 should have another set of users. So when I run chef, its not applying the set of users per that server role. Hope that makes better sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef client run is divided into 2 parts: compile and converge. In the first stage Chef creates a collection of resources that should be applied on the node and in the second stage it applies the changes. More on it [on the Chef docs](https://docs.chef.io/chef_client_overview.html)

You are assigning `node.normal['mainrole']` in converge state, but you check the values (`node['mainrole'] == "role1"`) in compile stage, which is before that.

You need to either move assigning to compile state or move checks into converge state.
One of the examples how to move checks into converge state is to use `not_if` or `only_if`. You will need 2 template resources in this case:

```
template "/etc/ssh/sshd_config for 1,2,3" do
  path "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
  source "ssh/sshd_config.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0600"
  action :create
  variables(:allowed_users_team1 => "AllowUsers user1 user2 user3")
  only_if { node['mainrole'] == "role1" }
  notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
end

template "/etc/ssh/sshd_config for 4,5,6" do
  path "/etc/ssh/sshd_config"
  source "ssh/sshd_config.erb"
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0600"
  action :create
  variables(:allowed_users_team2 => "AllowUsers user4 user5 user6")
  only_if { %w[role2 role3 role4].include? node['mainrole'] }
  notifies :restart, "service[sshd]", :immediately
end
```

Another way is to move the logic inside the template itself and pass 2 different variables:

```
  variables(:allowed_users_team2 => "AllowUsers user4 user5 user6",
    :allowed_users_team1 => "AllowUsers user1 user2 user3",
    :mainrole => node['mainrole'])
```